# XElement weirdness

Tags: linq-to-xml

XML Schemas allow us to exercise greater control over textual  content in text-only elements by providing built-in datatypes ( string,byte,int... ):

```
<xs:element name="root" type="xs:int"></xs:element>
```

But how do we create the above element using `XElement` class? Namely, if we pass to `XElement`'s constructor an `int` value ( say `20` ) representing element's content, this value will be converted to a `string` ( ie `XText` instance ) and treated as such:

```
      int int1 = 20;
      XElement element = new XElement("root",int1);
```

a) Is there a way to specify of which type should element's textual content be and if not, why not?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

`XElement`s store raw, unstructured XML; they have no awareness of the data inside of them.

If you want a strongly-typed API, you should build your own class that wrap or can create `XElement`s.

Comment: May I also ask --> "...have no awareness of the data inside of them." XElement is aware whether or not it contains any child elements ( which is some sort of data ), so any idea why XElement wasn't also designed to be able to specify the type of textual content?

Comment: `XElement` represents raw XML. Raw XML (as opposed to XSD) is untyped.